# Transition Probability of Orstein-Uhlenbeck Process using Girsanov's Theorem.

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, wiener-measure

How I can find the weak solution and transition distribution of Orstein-Uhlenbeck Process using Girsanov's Theorem. More specifically, suppose that
$$
dx_t = -\lambda \:x_t\:dt + \sigma\:d\beta_t,
$$
where $\beta_t$ is a wiener process. I want to compute the transition probability $P(x_t|x_s),~t\geq s$ based on the Girsanov's theorem.

As such, I define another process $y_t$ with $dy_t=d\beta_t$, and apply the Girsanov's theorem.
I then need to compute the likelihood ratio:
$$
z(t)= \exp\bigg(\int_0^t (y_0+\beta_t)d\beta_t - \frac12\int_0^t(y_0+\beta_t)^2dt \bigg)
$$
I can compute the integral $\int_0^t (y_0+\beta_t)d\beta_t$, but cannot compute $\int_0^t(y_0+\beta_t)^2dt$. As such, I cannot simplify $z(t)$. If I were able to have $z(t)$, then I could compute $P(x_t)$ using $P(x_t) = z(t)P(y_t)$ with $P(y_t)$ following a Normal distribution.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why Girsanov's theorem? I would use the approach explained in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699513/finding-pdf-px-1-from-px-0-given-sde-xt#comment9945681_4699513).