# Finding pdf p(x,1) from p(x,0) given sde Xt

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Assume $X_t$ satisfies the SDE:

$$dX_t = X_tdt + dW_t$$, where $W_t$ is standard normal.

If we know that $X_0 = 1$ and there exists some pdf of $X_t$, $p(x,0)$, how can I find the the pdf of $X_t$ at time 1, $p(x,1)?$

I tried to use Fokker–Planck equation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(x,t)= -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\mu(x,t)p(x,t)]+\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}[\sigma^2(x,t)p(x,t)]
$$, but I am not sure how I can utilize this equation without explicitly knowing $p(x,0)$.

Could you guys give me an advice on this problem? :D

Comment: You've seen that's an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process? His Green's function is well known and you can use Ito's Lemma to get the differential of the pdf.

Comment: What is big $P$ .?

Comment: @DonAbbondio Thank you! I will take a look on it :D

Comment: @EDX Oops! Sorry it should be little p ....

Comment: Fokker-Planck is overkill. Hint: $X_t$ is the Gaussian process $$
X_t=e^{t}X_0+e^{t}\int_0^te^{-s}\,dW_s\,.
$$ Knowing its mean and variance is enough to know $p(x,t)\,.$ The task is now very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial condition is given by $X_0 = 1$; in other words, the stochastic process $X_t$ is not random at the beginning. The distribution associated to a deterministic quantity is the Dirac delta, that is why one has $p(x,0) = \delta(x-1)$.

---

As stated by KurtG. in the comment section, the Fokker-Planck equation turns out to be some rather heavy machinery for the present purpose. In fact, $X_t$ is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, whose closed form is well-known, namely $X_t = X_0e^t + \int_0^t e^{t-s} \,\mathrm{d}W_s$ $-$ you can apply Itô's lemma on the transformation $Y_t := X_te^{-t}$ in order to rederive this result.

Since $\mathrm{d}W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathrm{d}t)$ is gaussian and normal law is stable, i.e. linear combinations of normal laws are also normal, we understand that $X_t$ is gaussian too $-$ because the integral is nothing else than a sum, $X_0$ a constant quantity and the exponentials some scalar prefactors.

Let's determine the mean and variance of $X_t$. Firstly, one has by linearity
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_t] 
   = \mathbb{E}\left[X_0e^t + \int_0^t e^{t-s} \,\mathrm{d}W_s\right] 
   = \mathbb{E}[X_0]e^t + \int_0^t e^{t-s} \,\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{d}W_s]
   = e^t
$$
since $\mathbb{E}[X_0] = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{d}W_t] = 0$. Then, [Itô's isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry) permits to compute its variance :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathrm{Var}[X_t] 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \mathbb{E}[(X_t-\mathbb{E}[X_t])^2] \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^t e^{t-s} \,\mathrm{d}W_s\right)^2\right] \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t e^{2(t-s)} \,\mathrm{d}s\right] \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \int_0^t e^{2(t-s)} \,\mathrm{d}s \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \left.\frac{e^{2(t-s)}}{-2}\right|_0^t \\
   &=&\displaystyle
   \frac{e^{2t}-1}{2}
\end{array}
$$
In conclusion, you have $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(e^t,\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2}\right)$, hence $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(e,\frac{e^2-1}{2}\right)$ and $p(x,1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(e^2-1)}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-e)^2}{e^2-1}\right)$.

Comment: Wow Thx!! Maybe I was overthinking = ]